# WPF: What is the event fired when auto creating a new control from datatemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, datatemplate

I have an `ObservableCollection<Tag> Tags` where the Tag class contains only a `string Content` property. I've created a `DataTemplate` that displays all tags and shows small buttons to delete and add new tags.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#676B6E" Margin="3">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Tag="{Binding}" Padding="0" Margin="2,0"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource RibbonButton}" Click="ButtonRemoveTagClick" Tag="{Binding}" Padding="0">
                <Image Height="12" Width="12" Source="/My Application;component/Resources/cross.png" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I add a new `Tag` to the collection I want the autocreated textbox to automatically select all the text inside and grab focus.

Is there an appropriate event I can handle on the textbox itself, or is there a better way to handle this?

I tried with `WpfExtendedToolkit.AutoSelectTextBox` but does not work the way I want.

Comment: You may try the Loaded event and see if the binding is already established then. Otherwise the first occurence of the TextChanged event may be suitable.

Comment: How do you add a `Tag` to the collection? Why can you not just do your select/focus operation in the code that adds the new item? The text box's `Loaded` event could work; you would need to add a flag to ensure you only select/focus on the first instance of the `TextChanged` event, to avoid infuriating the user. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing clearly what you've tried and the exact context of the question, it's not possible to provide a good answer.

Comment: I think the question is well written. I've missed to mention that the datatemplate is part of a WrapPanel datab ound to the Tags collection, but I really think in this case where the MVVM scheme is involved that is implied.
@Clemens Thanks for the quick response. The Loaded event did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the Loaded event of the TextBox did the trick.

```
    private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = sender as TextBox;

        tb.Focus();
        tb.SelectAll();
    }
```

Thanks to Clemens for the quick response.